# The items in Appium inspector as shows as ViewGroup (javascript)

Tags: javascript, testing, mobile, automation, appium

Actually I am testing cross-platform app, which is running on Android & iOS

The issue for me when I was using the Appium the items are displayed as view group and not appearing
in their real classes like Button, etc.

So, my question is that the normal behavior's ?, if not, is this issue from mobile dev team side, in which they can modify
somethings so that the classes in Appium will be displayed properly ?

Note: the language used for mobile dev team is JavaScript